# Difficulty in using php json_encode data received in javascript to display graph using chart.js library

Tags: javascript, php, json, chart.js

I am trying to display a graph using chart.js javascript library. The data I am fetching from database in PHP code and sending it to javascript by using `json_encode()` method to get in js var from PHP. The data actually is two fields of a table 'humidity' & 'temperature'. After receiving the data in js, when I try to fetch 'humidity' & 'temperature' values from the js object I received, I get `TypeError: jData is undefined` at line `hum = jData.humidity;` where jData is the parameter in js function receiving data from the script in PHP.

I try to parse the jData to convert it into js object before fetching values but then I receive `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character` at line `wData = JSON.parse(jData);`. Few posts on SO with same error tells that I the parse shouldn't be used as jData is already in js object form.

Here is my code:

php code:

```
 foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $k=>$v) {       
      $WData[] = $v;
    }
    ?>

    <script>
      var WData = <?php echo json_encode($WData);?>;
      console.log(WData);
      dspChrt(WData);
    </script>
```

js code:

```
function dspChrt(jData) { // to be called by loadChart() to render live chart

        //wData = JSON.parse(jData); 
        hum = jData.humidity;
        tem = jData.temperature;
        humArray.shift();
        humArray.push(hum);
        temArray.shift();
        temArray.push(tem);

        var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
        labels: ['01:00', '02:00', '03:00', '04:00', '05:00', '06:00', '07:00', '08:00', '09:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00', '22:00', '23:00', '00:00'],
        datasets: [{
        label: 'Humidity',
        data: humArray, // json value received used in method
        backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.4)"
            }, {
        label: 'Temprature',
        data: temArray,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
        }]
        }
    }); 
    }
```

Comment: What do you get in your console if you do `console.log(jData)` before parsing? Or I guess in your case the `console.log(WData);` would be the same

Comment: it shows the array data in the form:
(11811) […]
​[0…999]
​​[0…99]
​​​0: Object { humidity: "77.7", temperature: "22.1" }

Comment: So it's already an object, there is no need to do `JSON.parse()`. Do you get the same output if you do `console.log(jData)` inside the `dspChrt()` function?

Comment: I get same result whether I do log in php script part or in dsp(jData) function

Comment: but then it shows TypeError: jData is undefined as I described in OP

Comment: Inside the function, what if you do `console.log(jData[0])`?

Comment: {…}
​
humidity: "77.7"
​
temperature: "22.1"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
curl2js.php:24:21
undefined
and then after little time 
TypeError: jData is undefined

Comment: What stands out to me is your object return, the part that says `(11811) […] ​[0…999] ​​[0…99]`, makes me feel like your json is malformed somehow, but with the code you have here it should be working, so I'm at a loss, I'm sorry.

Comment: One more thing is if I do: console.log(hum); it gives undefined output. If you see console.log(jData[0]); output in above comment, undefined appear as last part of the array.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton; I found there was some mistake in writing console.log(jData[0]) command when I run earlier: This is the result it shows basically. Object { humidity: "77.7", temperature: "22.1" }

Answer (score -1):

With my previous experience on rendering the PHP json data inside JS, I could get it by rendering it as a string and then parse it. Something like this.

```
var WData = "'"+<?php echo json_encode($WData);?>+"'";
 jData= JSON.parse(wData);
```

Comment: Can you help me understand how to put this in my code. What I understood is I replace       var WData = <?php echo json_encode($WData);?>; with var WData = "'"+<?php echo json_encode($WData);?>+"'"; in php code. While about  jData= JSON.parse(wData); . Do you mean I parse it after to jData receiving in the dspchrt(wData) ?

Comment: I used in the way I mentioned & I get same error as before with parsing i.e. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data